# SQL command for replacing?

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I have data in the following format in my postgres table:

```
 create table t (col1 character varying, col2 character varying, col3 character varying);

  col1   col2    col3
  <a>    <b>     <c> .
  <d>    owl:g   <h> .
  dbp:h1  <k>     <l> .
```

I need to substitute any blank occurence with http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/VARIABLE
and

```
  owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#VARIABLE>
  dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/VARIABLE>
```

I know it is possible to achieve the same in python using re.sub(r"<(.*?)>", r"http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/\1", col)

My converted data would look like the following:

```
<http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/a>    <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/b>    <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/c>
<http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/d>    <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/g>      <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/h> 
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/h1>          <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/k>    <http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/l>
```

Is it possible to achieve the same using SQL in postgres?  Also in col3 there is a dot after each value, is it possible to eliminate that dot using SQL

EDIT: I tried the following using regex:

```
regexp_replace('<a>', '.[<a]a.', '<http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/')
```

However, it does not seem to work. Can anyone point out as to where am I going wrong.

Comment: look at `regexp_replace` in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Comment: @Laurence Thanks a lot for the help. However I am unable to understand as to what does 'mN' mean in regexp_replace('Thomas', '.[mN]a.', 'M'). Can you please explain with the help of a short example

Comment: `[mN]a` is the regular expression that defines the search criteria.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks a lot for the help. Isnt my search criteria in [<a]..then why is it not giving me the desired results. Can you please explain with the help of a short example

Answer (score 1):

It'll probably be easier to package this up into a function. This should get you started:

```
Create Function squirrel(col varchar) returns varchar as $$
begin
  col = regexp_replace(col, ' \.$', '');
  col = regexp_replace(col, '<(.)>', '<http://yago-knowledge.org/resource/\1>');
  col = regexp_replace(col, 'owl:(.*)', '<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#\1>');
  col = regexp_replace(col, 'dbp:(.*)', '<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/#\1>');

  return col;
end;
$$ Language plpgsql;

Select 
  squirrel(col1) col1,
  squirrel(col2) col2,
  squirrel(col3) col3
from
  t
```

**<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/295c7/1)</kbd>**